# Show separators for WindowCommands when using databound ItemsControl in MahApps.Metro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mahapps.metro

When manually adding buttons as window commands, the separators show up normally:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <controls:WindowCommands ShowSeparators="True">
        <Button Content="Button1" />
        <Button Content="Button2" />
    </controls:WindowCommands>
</controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

[image: desired look]

When trying to dynamically create buttons as window commands in XAML using an ItemsControl, I can't get the separators to show up correctly. The buttons themselves look correct aside from the margin/padding which will likely be fixed when the separators are fixed.

Here's my XAML:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <controls:WindowCommands ShowSeparators="True">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GamesViewModel.Games}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:Game}">
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </controls:WindowCommands>
</controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

[image: not working]

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? I thought it might have something to do with the ItemsPanel I'm setting, but I had to do that to make the buttons horizontal. Perhaps there's a style/template I'm overriding?

This code-behind version does work, but I'd rather do it all through XAML:

```
foreach (Game game in ((MainViewModel)DataContext).GamesViewModel.Games)
    WindowCommands.Items.Add(new Button { Content = game.Name });
```

[image: code-behind working]

Comment: As for the "why", I added another ItemsControl in my XAML below the existing one, and it put a separator between the 2 ItemsControls, so it essentially treats each ItemsControl as one control in the control collection. If anyone has any ideas on a XAML workaround, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've already noticed the problem without realising it! `WindowCommands` *is* an `ItemsControl` itself so just give it an `ItemsSource` and it'll be sorted.

The key thing is to feed it `WindowCommandsItem` instead of your viewmodel (this really feels like a bug in 0.13 alpha series where i tested as it used to work without this special conversion in past if memory serves.)

Here's bits of code that I tested it with:

#### XAML Bits:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
    <wpfApplication1:ViewModel />
</controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
<controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfApplication1:Model}">
        <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <wpfApplication1:ModelToWindowCommandsItemConverter x:Key="Converter" />
</controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
<controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <controls:WindowCommands ItemsSource="{Binding Commands, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
</controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

#### Converter code used:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{ return ((IEnumerable<Model>)value).Select(x => new WindowCommandsItem { Content = x }); }
```

#### ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Commands { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Model>
    {
        new Model { Name = "Skyrim" },
        new Model { Name = "Fallout 4" },
        new Model { Name = "Fallout NV" }
    };
}
```

#### Model:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

#### Result:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! The only thing I changed was having the converter return a collection of Buttons instead of WindowCommandItems, but either would have worked.

Comment: oh, I prefered to work with WindowCommandItems because then i can leave my data templates for models to work as rest of the application handles them. Returning a button will limit you to button styles only.

Answer (score 0):

In connection with @Maverik answer, there is no need to use a converter for it. Just put the `DataTemplate` on `WindowCommands.ItemTemplate`.

```
<controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <controls:WindowCommands ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
        <controls:WindowCommands.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Model}">
                <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:WindowCommands.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:WindowCommands>
</controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

Comment: I tried this solution and several variations but can't get it to work. Nothing happens. I tried debugging with a converter, but the converter code isn't hit, so I'm assuming I have to re-set the data context somewhere inside the data template.